# preg_replace is not working - nothing changes

Tags: php, preg-replace

I obtained next pattern from one of my cms validations:

```
'/^[^0-9!<>,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:¤|]*$/u'
```

And I have a form where I send to php firstname variable, which has to pass previous validation. So I make preg_replace to sanitize the string.
I make this:

```
preg_replace('/^[0-9!<>,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:¤|]*$/u', '', $firstname);
```

But nothing changes.
Can help please?

https://regexr.com/56u94

Comment: what is the string for `$firstname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace all that characters with an empty string, so stripping out. You have to use the regex a little bit different.

```
preg_replace('/[0-9!<>,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:¤|]/u', '', "foobar_123123_&90481");
```

https://3v4l.org/RUk4Z

Explanation: With ^ you say the string must begin with one of that characters. With $ you say it must end with one of that characters. With * you say 0 or more characters of that type.

But all you want is to replace each characters that matches with an empty string, so you not need those `^, $ and *` modifiers/limiters.